# Why added input field in sweet alert not allowing to edit?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

This is my code to display dialog box using sweet alert.

```
swal({
            title: "Confirm?",
            text:'<input id="datepicker" class="form-control" autofocus>',
            type: "warning",
            customClass: 'swal-custom-width',
            html:true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
            confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true
        },
```

In order to display input field, i overwrite the css with

> display : initial;

My input field displayed after i apply the css. But the input field not allowing to edit.

I have tried other input type as well, same problem. It will throw error when click on the field.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
at HTMLDivElement.trigger (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
at Object.trigger (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
at Function.each (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4)
at c.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
at HTMLDocument.f (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Are you sure this error occurs because of `swal` ? It seems you have written a `$.each` loop, that triggers an event, which might itself call the foreach loop, etc. Can you show a little more context (code)?

Comment: @Barthy It triggers when i click on <input id="datepicker" class="form-control" autofocus> this input field

Comment: Well, for some reason one of your javascript functions keeps on calling itself. That's the definition of a call stack error. Can you debug or post more relevant code? What you have written now, isn't the culprit.

Comment: As @Loek and I said, without any more code we won't be able to help you. [Read this to help us help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By right the input field show inside sweet alert should allow to edit and input value, but mine not allowed to edit or input value. I applied date time picker to the input field then it caused this issue.